# hadoop conf "fs.default.name" can't be setted ip:port format directly?

Tags: hadoop

all

I have setupped a hadoop cluster in fully distributed mode. First, I set core-site.xml "fs.default.name" and mapred-site.xml "mapred.job.tracker" in hostname:port format, and chang /etc/hosts correspondingly, the cluster works succesfully.

Then I use another way, I set set core-site.xml "fs.default.name" and mapred-site.xml "mapred.job.tracker" in ip:port format. It dosen't work.

I find
***ERROR org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Error getting localhost name. Using 'localhost'...***
 in namenode log file  and

***ERROR org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Error getting localhos
t name. Using 'localhost'...
java.net.UnknownHostException: slave01: slave01: Name or service not known***

in datanode log file.

In my opinion,ip and hostname is equivalent. Is there something wrong in my hadoop conf?

Comment: Not sure why the exception, but it's from InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(). Here is the [code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/impl/MetricsSystemImpl.java) for MetricsSystemImpl.java. I don't think it's a problem with the configuration files.

Comment: why can I succeed in first way? The only changed factor is the configuration file, So I infer that there is something wrong with ip:port format

Comment: maybe this would solve your problem [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725804/hadoop-pseudo-distributed-mode-datanode-and-tasktracker-not-starting

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is a wrong configured hostname in /etc,

you should check hostname  /etc/hosts /etc/HOSTNAME (rhel/debian) or rc.conf (archlinux) etc.

Comment: I succeeded in hostname:port format, but failed in ip:port format. So there is definitely no error in my /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts files.

Answer (score 0):

I got your point. This is because of that you probably wrote in mapred-site.xml, hdfs://ip:port (it starts with hdfs, this is wrong) but when you write hostname:port, you probably did not write hdfs at the beginning of the value which is correct way. THerefore, firstone did not work,but, second has worked

Fatih haltas

Answer (score 0):

I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230946/hdfs-lan-ip-address-hostname-resolution).

It seems that HDFS uses host name only for it's all communication and display purposes, so we can NOT use ip directly in core-site.xml and mapred-site.xml