# hdfs LAN ip address hostname resolution

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am setting up hdfs cluster of 2 slaves on my LAN.

Whenever I give ip address of them. HDFS tries to get the hostname from it.

Can it work only on ip addresses on not hostname.

Is there a setting to tell work only with ip addresses and not hostnames?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it cannot work on IP addresses alone.

> For the cluster to function correctly, the  part of the
>   string must be the hostname (for example *mynamenode*) not the IP
>   address.

Read more [here](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Deploying+HDFS+on+a+Cluster).

Also to quote from [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml), the explanation for the config `dfs.datanode.dns.nameserver` goes as follows:

> The host name or IP address of the name server (DNS) which a DataNode
>   should use to determine **the host name used by the NameNode for
>   communication and display purposes**.

So it seems that HDFS uses host name only for it's all communication and display purposes.

Comment: But LAN ips do not have legit hostnames. What are the best practices? Can I create fake hostnames in my /etc/hosts file